# How do you remove the partialFill from Highcharts xrange chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

want to use X-range Chart with the number and percentage that shows up in the bars completely removed.

From the documentation, I thought that putting undefined as a parameter in partialFill would remove this completely. But it just seems to cause the Bar to show a Zero percent.

```
          partialFill: 0.25
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/x-range/

Here is the link above to HighCharts demo version of their xrange chart. Here is the code below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
         type: 'xrange'
   },
   title: {
         text: 'Highcharts X-range'
   },
   xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime'
   },
   yAxis: {
          title: {
          text: ''
    },
   categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
   reversed: true
},
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    // pointPadding: 0,
    // groupPadding: 0,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        y: 0,
        partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        y: 2
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
        y: 2
    }],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the whole point or just the data label ("0%")?

Comment: I want to hide any character besides the colored data bar itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone named Daniel, answered this question on the Highcharts Forum, I will give his answer below:

hi KodaroKid,

If I understood correctly, you mean that you don't want to show the dataLabels of points without partialFill to on the chart, right? If yes, in order to achieve the effect you expecting, you need to use dataLabels.formatter function, and check whether the partialFill is defined in specific point, then format and display its value. Otherwise return the empty string. Please take a look at code below:

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/fmca01cz/

```
     dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var percents = this.point.partialFill
          return percents ? percents * 100 + '%' : ''
      }
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.dataLabels.formatter

Best regards!